# Specify wildcard in JSON?

Tags: sql, json, rest, jersey

I have searched the web, but I cannot find an answer (or a duplicate question for that matter).

I am POSTing JSON via Jersey REST services.

I usually POST something like this, where each value is specified:

```
{
    "w":"val1",
    "x":"val2",
    "y":"val3",
    "z":{
        "zz":{
            "za":"val9",
            "zb":"val8",
            "zc":"val7"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to POST something like this, where the asterisk is a wildcard.

```
{
    "w":"val1",
    "x":"val2",
    "y":"val3",
    "z":{
        "zz":{
            "za":"val9",
            "zb":"*",
            "zc":"val7"
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON values will ultimately be passed as parameters to a Sybase Stored procedure, but in this case I do not know any valid values for "zb".

For example, "zb" may be a primary key ID.  But I do not know any of the 10 digit ID's.  So rather than repeatedly trying random combinations of 10 digits until I get a result back, I would like to specify that ANY existing primary key in the table would suffice.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Why not just accept 'null' and not filter by that parameter if its null?

Comment: What you suggst is valid JSON, so you can send what you have. It will be down to the server to determine what action it should take if it sees an `*` in the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having a complete Q&A repository on this website, I am posting what I have come up with, although it is an unsatisfactory solution.

My workaround is a combination of (at the time of this writing) the two comments left to the question.

That being said, I did not specify a "wildcard" character.  I POSTed empty strings for data I did not have, and, of course, received a broader data set in the response.  For example, my JSON looked something like this:

```
{
    "w":"val1",
    "x":"",
    "y":"val3",
    "z":{
        "zz":{
            "za":"",
            "zb":"",
            "zc":"val7"
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I could not do exactly what I wanted to do as described in the question. That is either because (it's still unknown to me) 1) it is currently impossible to do what I am trying to do in JSON or 2) it is possible, but I still do not know how.